# Как установить библиотеку ActionBarSherlock?

Tags: actionbarsherlock, android, lib

Как установить библиотеку ActionBarSherlock?

Скачала архив с официального сайта. Распаковала. 
Добавляю как проект. 
Что из этого нужно добавить как новый проект: 
[image]

Comment: actionbarsherlock -___-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте его через `gradle` (из документации):

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
}
```

[`actionbarsherlock.com: usage`](http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html)

Comment: @ua6xh качала я с этого сайта http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html

Comment: @lmire - у них есть репозиторий на [github][1]

[1]: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock